# AfterAll Uncaught TypeError: localStorage.removeItem is not a function thrown

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am new to Angular testing, so i have tested small events and function but now working with fake localStorage while testing i am facing this issue `localStorage.removeitem` in every component. I have googled this issue but could't get the best possible solution. Can anyone help to overcome this problem.

This is how i mock the local storage for testing.

```
let store = {''}; // i have localData here

    const mockLocalStorage = {
        getItem: (key: string): string => {
        return key in store ? store[key] : null;
        },
        setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
        store[key] = `${value}`;
        },
        removeItem: (key: string) => {
        delete store[key];
        },
        clear: () => {
            this.store = {};
        }
    };

    spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem')
        .and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.getItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem')
        .and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.setItem);
    // spyOn(localStorage, 'removeItem')
    //     .and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.removeItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'clear')
        .and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.clear);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't mock the `localStorage` since it is on the window object and its implementation is pretty easy. Mocking it might bring more headaches than needed.

Just let `localStorage` be what it is on the `window` object and if you want `localStorage` to be fresh from test to test, in `afterAll` hook, do `localStorage.clear();`.

Comment: Yes but that will remove all items. My point is that don't mock `localStorage`, use it properly for your tests and once you are done with using it in a suite, in the `afterAll` hook, do `localStorage.clear()` so you're back to a clean slate for your other tests.